# Order of text jumbled when printing

Tags: terminal, special-characters, data

We run an automated process which changes the data structure in a file, and it has run for about a year without any issues.  It has just started failing and I have narrowed the problem down to one of the date fields in the file.  The files before and after the problem started look identical however there is something going on.  If I try and print the file to the screen with other text it jumbles the order.  I can't find any hidden characters in the file although I suspect there must be one.  Anyone seen this before?

Here is an example.  I trimmed everything out of the file other than the dodgy fields and compare an old file with a new one:

```
$ cat old.file
16-JUN-2015
15-JUN-2015
$ cat old.file | awk '{print "a" $1 "b"}'
a16-JUN-2015b
a15-JUN-2015b
$ for line in `cat old.file`;do echo "a${line}b";done
a16-JUN-2015b
a15-JUN-2015b
$
$
$ cat new.file
23-JUN-2015
16-JUN-2015
$ cat new.file | awk '{print "a" $1 "b"}'
b23-JUN-2015
b16-JUN-2015
$ for line in `cat new.file`;do echo "a${line}b";done
b23-JUN-2015
b16-JUN-2015
```

I'm runnin Red Hat EL Server.  Thanks,

Comment: This is probably a `new-line` vs `cariage-return` issue. I think the new file only has the cariage-return `^M` characters instead of newlines. Try `file /path/to/new.file` and see if it returns `ASCII text, with CR line terminators`

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the issue: `new.file: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators` vs `old.file: ASCII text`.  Can I fix it?

Comment: You could for instance use `dos2unix` to convert the file line endings but I would recommend to you to see which process is writing the `new.file` to diagnose which part is responsible for writing the CR line endings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have somehow got Windows style line endings, ie `CRLF` `\x0D\xOA` `\r\n` ...

```
printf 'xyz\r\n' >file; cat file | awk '{print "a" $1 "b"}'
```

outputs `bxyz`

---

```
cat file | sed -n l
```

outputs `xyz\r$` - The `$` inidcates end-of line

---

You can filter out any extrandous `\r`s from a `\r\n` pair with `awk`

```
cat file | awk -vRS='\r?\n' 1 | sed -n l
```

Outputs `xyz$`

---

To correct the problem:

```
cat file | awk -vRS='\r?\n' 1 > file.fixed
```

---

Why this behaviour?

When the `cat file` output is displayed on a terminal, the `\r` (Carriage-Return), does what it is(was) intended to do, ie. *Return the Carriage* fully to the left. For the terminal, this means that the text-insertion point is moved to the left edge of the screen - the terminology and concept of `\r` derrives from the manual typewriter era, when the *Carriage* was *Returned* to the left margin (by a hand operated lever), and once at the left margin, the roller would advance the paper down by 1 line, ie, it *Fed* the paper 1 *Line*.

In the terminal, because you have `b` after `\r`, the `b` overwrites the previouly placed `a` in column 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a `new-line` vs `cariage-return` issue. I think the new file only has the cariage-return `^M` characters instead of newlines. Try `file /path/to/new.file` and see if it returns `ASCII text, with CR line terminators`

In your case the `a` is printed followed by the input line which has the `^M` line terminator, telling to go the beginning of the line and then print `b`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a carriage return in the new file (^M) instead of a linefeed (^J) at the end of the line.  Try using cat -v new.file and also looking at the file using hd.

You can remove the extraneous carriage returns using sed like this:

sed 's/\r//' new.file

Comment: If it didn't have LFs, the file would be a single line. More likely the file is in Microsoft format with CR+LF line delimitors.